# PHP SQLSRV: Does sqlsrv_query() works to prepare a select statement, right way?

Tags: php, sql-server

**TL:DR**

Does `sqlsrv_query()` do the same job for `select` statements than `sqlsrv_prepare()` and `sqlsrv_execute()` do, regarding prepared statements?

How could I do a safe `select` statement?

**A little history**

I'm a newbie regarding PHP development, and I got an old (non-OO) PHP application to maintain and refactor all those spaghetti codes. In fact, I made a Repository and a Service abstraction, to put a little of Object Orientation inside the project in a separated area, without messing with what is working nowadays.

I've made this abstraction considering a future PDO inclusion. Today i'm just refactoring code by steps. Doctrine and other ORMs are not an option for today (Project Manager decision, unfortunately... Not my fault).

Well, we are using `sqlsrv` driver here, and I've seen how to prepare and execute a statement for an `insert` or `update` operations. The question is: How could I prepare a `select` statement for execution (helping prevent 1st order injection attacks), similarly I do with `sqlsrv_prepare()` and `sqlsrv_execute()`?

Configs: PHP 5.3, Sql Server.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you could just read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php  there's code examples all over the php.net docs.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering! I've already read the docs. I've done my generic insert and update operations just like the docs (with prepared statements - sqlsrv_prepare() and sqlsrv_execute()). Does sqlsrv_query() work the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php

> Prepares a query for execution

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php

> Prepares **and executes a query**.

In prepared statements you send the query and parameters separately. As such, you need two separate calls (with [sqlsrv_execute](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-execute.php) providing the other end of that duo).

`sqlsrv_query()` simply sends the SQL for immediate execution. It does NOT support prepared statements so you will have to have sanitized data included inline.

Comment: According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15): `The sqlsrv_query function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries.` Doesn't this mean the input will be bound as parameters to a statement prepared on-the-go, and will not require sanitization? Can you please clarify/explain?

Comment: @funforums In most other DB API systems (like PDO), you typically have multiple functions to prepare, but `sqlsrv_query()` does both the prepare, bind(s) and execution all at once. You do not need to sanitize (for SQL purposes anyways) any data passed in the `params` argument because they will be passed as prepared arguments.

Comment: Then the question about difference remains the same! Help