# What is the best way to securely save data into MSSQL using PHP (sqlsrv)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, object, sqlsrv

I have the following object which I am parsing from Javascript to PHP via an AJAX post request.

[image]

What is the best way to safely insert this data into SQL using PHP?

All of the keys of the object exist as columns in a table. So I thought that I'd need to find a way to loop through the object and create a statement like:

```
insert into table (email, first_name, last_name) VALUES ('email@host.net', 'Joe', 'Bloggs'),('email2@host2.net', 'Fred', 'Flintstone')
```

However, I have a suspicion that this method would open me up to the risk of SQL injection.

I have heard of 'Prepared Statements' as a way to accomplish the this with mysqli however, I am not sure if this works in sqlsrv.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$serverName = "server";
$connInfo = array("Database"=>"database", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connInfo);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $data = json_decode($json, true);  ///  <----- THIS IS THE OBJECT WHICH HAS BEEN PARSED FROM JS VIA AJAX
  $sql = ""; /// <--- I need to create an insert statement???

  /////Execute the statement
  if($conn){
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
    if( $stmt === false ) {
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }//end if
    echo json_encode("Record created successfully. ");
  }//end if
  /////End of Execute the statement

}//end if
else{
  echo json_encode("ERROR: record did not save correctly to MSSQL.");
  die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}//end else
?>
```

Comment: You might have heard that, but it's not entirely correct. You can not provide the names of the columns in prepared statements (by design). Additionally just adding "prepared statement" as sauce on top would not make the operation safe per-se. If you study the SQL language of Sqlserver and study how prepared statements work, you should be able to create yourself a SQL query builder (with prepared statement support) that you then can use. As you concern about safety, this is hard work with no simple answers. But maybe there is an alternative approach to that, like working with database metainfo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835418/php-sqlsrv-does-sqlsrv-query-works-to-prepare-a-select-statement-right-way